# GetOrDefault<T> without relying on InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to find a way to have a generic method that retrieves a setting value and casts it to the generic type.  I'd really like to avoid getting a first chance InvalidCastException when the casts fail.

Here's some code that works but contains a first chance exception on cast failure:

```
T IAppSettings.Get<T>(string settingKey)
{
  if (!ContainsSetting(settingKey))
    return default(T);

  var val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingKey];
  try
  {
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
  }
  catch (InvalidCastException)
  {
    return default(T);
  }
}
```

And here's what i was hoping to do, but the AS command doesn't seem to work with generics:

```
T IAppSettings.Get<T>(string settingKey)
{
  if (!ContainsSetting(settingKey))
    return default(T);

  var val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingKey];
  var result = val as T;  //invalid code - Parameter T cannot be used with 'as' operator

  return result ?? default(T);
}
```

Are there any working alternatives that avoid exceptions?

Comment: are you dealing with `struct`s or `class`es?

Comment: If `T` is always a class, then add `where T : class` constraint.

Comment: They're always classes.  Adding the constraint fixed the compilation issue for using 'as'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `where T : class` to your method's declaration.

The reason behind it is that as per specification:
*In an operation of the form e as T, e must be an expression and T must be a reference type*. Now in order to fulfill this, you need to tell the compiler that your T is going to be of a reference type (e.g. a class).

Comment: Thanks.  This resolved the issue for using 'as'.  For anyone else looking for an answer, here's how the new method signature looks: _T Get<T>(String settingKey) where T : class_

Comment: @BillTarbell And of course there is no need to use `default(T)` in that case. You can just `return val as T;` then.

Comment: While this might "solve" the compilation error, it just moves the problem to the runtime. First of all, almost everything you need to get from AppSettings (except string) is not a class, but value type. Second, AppSettings[key] returns a string, so it really needs a **conversion**, not a cast.

Comment: @IvanStoev is right. The compile-time type is a `string` (which is a `sealed` type, of course), so using `as` with that is not really interesting. You always know that either the `val` is a null reference, or else it has type `string` (which has direct base class `object` and which implements some interfaces including `IConvertible`, cf. the asker's old code).